# Selecting text from many textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textbox

I have few textboxes one below another. Every textbox has a different text and I want to select text from it all like it was a one textbox.

Normally when I select text in one TB and i pass the Textbox bounds it won't select text in another one. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
|------------------| 
|                  |
|      first       | 
|------------------| 

|------------------| 
|                  | 
|     second       | 
|------------------| 

|------------------| 
|                  | 
|       third      |    
|------------------|
```

You press LMB on third and drag it over first and it select all of them - that's what I want to get.

Comment: What do you mean `select`? Do you want to retrieve the text from all textboxes and combine it as one? Or do you mean highlighting all text in all textboxes?

Comment: That would be a very wierd UI behaviour. Why can't you use a single, multiline textbox?

Comment: Could you maybe also supply us with a screenshot or a piece of the code?

Comment: By "select" I mean highlight that text and enable user to ctrl + C it.

Comment: And i can't use a single multiline textbox beceause every of em are in different DataTemplated element and it couldn't be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You may group them into for exapmle *panel* and use this:

```
    private string getText(Control parent)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        foreach (Control aktControl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (aktControl is TextBox)
            { output += (aktControl as TextBox).Text; }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Or with ordering:

```
private string getText(Control parent)
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    List<TextBox> lTB = new List<TextBox>();

    foreach (Control aktControl in parent.Controls)
    { if (aktControl is TextBox) lTB.Add((aktControl as TextBox)); }

    lTB = lTB.OrderBy(tb => tb.Name).ToList();

    foreach (TextBox aktTextBox in lTB)
    { output += aktTextBox.Text; }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: I know how to get all the text contained in those textboxes beceause it's in templated object. I want to enable user to hihlight (select) like it was in same textbox

|------------------|
|                  |
|     first        |
|------------------|

|------------------|
|                  |
|     second       |
|------------------|

|------------------|
|                  |
|     third        |
|------------------|

You press LMB on third and drag it over first and it select all of them - that's what I want to get.

Comment: Damn, how to write it with [enter]? :P

Comment: Hmm... Interesting ... So then I do not know how :)